# position div under min-height div

Tags: css

My question here is - how to position div to stick at the bottom of another div that has min-height style atribute.
It looks like this

```
    |-------------------|
    |wrapper            |
    |----------|--------|
    |min-height|min-heig|
    |   div    |   div  |
    |----------|--------|
    |div that keeps     |
    |     disappearing  |
    |-------------------|
```

So my problem is that if the min-height divs are expanding, than the "div that keeps disappearing" flows right under the extension of those divs, how can i fix that?
Code -

```
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="left" style="float:left;min-height:200px;">
      content
      </div>
      <div id="right" style="min-height:200px;">
      content
      </div>
      <div id="disappearing" style="height:100px;">
      content
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: Please add some code so we can better help you.

Comment: sorry for that, forgot to add code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a clearing element between the min-height divs and the disappearing div would be enough to fix your issue.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left" style="border: 1px solid Red;float:left;min-height:200px;height:600px;">content</div>
    <div id="right" style="border: 1px solid Green;min-height:200px; height:400px;">content</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="disappearing" style="border: 1px solid Blue;height:100px;">content</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VBEfL/

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the most reliable and maintainable solution in cases like this is to use a grid system. An excellent article is [Chris Coyier's "Don't Overthink It Grids"](http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/).

Here's the basic, cut-down bit:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="grid">
      <div id="left" class="col-1-2 module-min-200">
      content
      </div>
      <div id="right" class="col-1-2 module-min-200">
      content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
      <div id="disappearing" class="module-fixed-100">
      content
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
}

.col-1-2 { width: 50%; }
.col-1-4 { width: 25%; }
.col-3-4 { width: 75%; }
.col-1-8 { width: 12.5%; }
.col-1-3 { width: 33.33%; }
.col-2-3 { width: 66.66%; }

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

[class*='col-']:last {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.grid-pad {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
}

.grid-pad > [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.module-fixed-100 { height: 100px; }
.module-min-200 { min-height: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#disappearing{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}
```